# How to specifically detect a touch screen display on Windows 8?

Tags: input, windows-8, microsoft-metro, hid

I am developing an app that needs to detect whether or not a touch screen is present. I am using the following code which works for the most part:

```
TouchCapabilities^ tc = ref new TouchCapabilities();

return tc->TouchPresent;
```

The problem is that I have a laptop where this is returning true for the touchpad, there is no touch screen. I have tried to detect whether there is a touch screen present with the following code, but it never breaks inside the touch screen section. I admit I am not very confident in my understanding of HID.

```
Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<PointerDevice^>^ devices = Windows::Devices::Input::PointerDevice::GetPointerDevices();

for (int i = 0; i < devices->Size; ++i)
{
    PointerDevice^ pd = devices->GetAt(i);

    PointerDeviceType pdt = pd->PointerDeviceType;
    unsigned int contacts = pd->MaxContacts;
    bool integrated = pd->IsIntegrated;

    for (int j = 0; j < pd->SupportedUsages->Size; ++j)
    {
        PointerDeviceUsage pdu = pd->SupportedUsages->GetAt(j);

        unsigned int usagePage = pdu.UsagePage;

        if (usagePage == 0x0D) // 0x0D is the Digitizer HID Usage Page
        {
            unsigned int usage = pdu.Usage;

            if (pdu.Usage == 0x04) // 0x04 is the Touch Screen HID Usage ID
            {
                 // Should be touch screen but never goes in here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to specifically detect a touch screen? If so is it possible to see some example code?

Comment: note that if the Visual Studio simulator is running, you'll get a TRUE for TouchPresent, even if you're running the app outside of the simulator.  That may or may not be germane here.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Did you want to put that up as an answer so I can accept it. Even though the simulator wasn't running on the machine, opening and closing it has rectified the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TouchCapabilities.TouchPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.touchcapabilities.touchpresent.aspx) should do the trick; however, be aware that if the Visual Studio simulator is loaded, your application will report that there is touch capability even if you are running the application locally (i.e., not within the simulator).

Comment: ah!  I've got the simulator installed, so THAT'S why it keeps telling me I've got touch when I know I haven't!  +10 if I could! Thanks.